# Laravel 5 get name based on ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a users and departments table. So my departments table might have a row like so

```
 id | departmentName         
----------------------
 2  | Marketing       
----------------------
```

And the users table might have something like

```
 id | name       | email                | departmentId           
-------------------------------------------------------
 18 | Nick       | nick@email.com       | 2   
-------------------------------------------------------
```

So the users table links to the departments table via the id.

So now onto my UserController, in the index function, I do

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

Now that will display everything within my users table.

My problem is, I do not want to display the departmentId.  I want to display the departmentName which is linked to that departmentID.  So in the above example, my users index page for that one row should show Marketing, not 2.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships). What you described in your question is a [One-to-Many Relation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), meaning a department can have many users, and each user belongs to a department. So you'll need to setup a model for your `departments` table (if you haven't done so already) and then define the relationship in your `User` model like so:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Department', 'departmentId');
    }
}
```

You can then access the department details in your view via that relationship:

```php
@foreach ($users as $user)
    {{ $user->department->departmentName }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks.  I do have a Model and relationship set up.  Where you get the departmentName, would this be done inside the controller alongside where I do User:all()?  And then I pass this to the view?  Or can I do it directly within the view?  Thanks

Comment: You can do that directly in the view.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more relevant usage example.

Comment: When I try doing it directly within the view I get the error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: No worries, with your update, it works perfectly.  Thanks