# Laravel 5 relationships with two tables

Tags: laravel-5

This question is kind of related to this
[Laravel 5 get name based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180355/laravel-5-get-name-based-on-id)

The above questions problem is solved, works perfectly.  Now I am trying to do something similar but with more relationships.

So I have a users table

```
 id | name       | email                | departmentId           
-------------------------------------------------------
 1 | Nick       | nick@email.com       | 2   
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I also have a clients table

```
 id | clientName         
-----------------
 18 | McDonalds     
-----------------
```

So these tables are straight forward.  Then I have a projects table

```
id | projectName     | clientId     | userId             
-------------------------------------------------------
18 | Test Project    | 18           | 1   
-------------------------------------------------------
```

So this table links to the clients and users tables.  A project can have one client and many users.  So in Project.php I have

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Client', 'clientId');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\user', 'userId');
}
```

And then in Client.php

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
}
```

And User.php

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
}
```

So I think the relationships are set up ok.  I have some data in the database but when I try to view the index page I get the error.

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clients.clientId' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `clients` where `clients`.`clientId` = 2 and `clients`.`clientId` is not null limit 1)
```

My mitegations seem to have the correct names

```
$table->integer('clientId')->unsigned()->default(0);
$table->foreign('clientId')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->integer('userId')->unsigned()->default(0);
$table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Is there anything in the information I have shown which might be causing this error?  Or is there anything else I can add?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, according to your given `projects` table below, the relationship is opposite:

```
id | projectName     | clientId     | userId             
-------------------------------------------------------
18 | Test Project    | 18           | 1   
-------------------------------------------------------
```

The above `projects` table dictates as:

```
Client hasOne Project
User hasOne Project
Project belongsTo user
Project belongsTo Client
```

If you use one user_id/client_id in more than one project than it'll be hasMany. If you want to do what you asked for then you need to alter the database schema. For making it sounds like this:

```
Project hasOne Client (Use project_id in clients table as foreign key)
Project hasMany User (Use project_id in users table as foreign key)
```

Hope you got the idea.